# Where does the table mutation take place here (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I'm dealing with oracle SQL now, and trying to create a trigger. For some reasonn it shows me the mutated table error, however, I don't see where it gets mutated at all (it's just a select without even counts, however, it has joins). Where should I at least start in writing a compound trigger for the solution? There seems to be just a few examples and they are too far from mine to understand how it should work at all in this particular situation.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "EVGENIJ_BOBROVICH"."FIX_UPD_LIMITS" 
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON "EVGENIJ_BOBROVICH"."MAP_CALCULATION_SHOP_LIMITS"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
is_deleted_dependant VARCHAR2(1 BYTE);
is_editable_dependant VARCHAR2(1 BYTE);
BEGIN
SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE INTO is_deleted_dependant, is_editable_dependant
FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG
ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC INNER JOIN map_calculation_shop_limits MS ON MG.ID_GROUP = ms.id_group
WHERE :OLD.ID_GROUP = MG.ID_GROUP AND MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC;
IF UPDATING AND (is_editable_dependant = 'F' OR is_deleted_dependant = 'T') THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20004, '....Error......' );   
ELSIF DELETING AND (is_editable_dependant = 'F' OR is_deleted_dependant = 'T') THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20005, '...AnotherError...' );   
END IF;
END;
/
```

The select itself without a trigger (without the into and old of course as well, I used a bind variable instead of old) works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens here:

```
INNER JOIN map_calculation_shop_limits
```

You can't select from the same table you're updating as it is ... well, *mutating*.

For updating purposes, you'd

```
 FROM map_calculation mc
      INNER JOIN map_calculation_group mg ON mc.id_calc = mg.id_calc
      -- INNER JOIN map_calculation_shop_limits MS ON MG.ID_GROUP = ms.id_group       --> this
WHERE     :old.id_group = mg.id_group
      AND mg.id_calc = mc.id_calc
      AND mg.id_group = :new.id_group;          --> and this
```

For deleting, you'd use `:old.id_group` which means that you'll need to rewrite code you use into two parts: one that'll handle updates, and another to handle deletes.